# Когда запускаю Docker контейнер, не могу работать в терминале Docker хоста

Tags: docker

Только начал изучать Docker. Вопросы возможно глупые, не могу разобраться сам, помогите.

У меня такой стек: `Windows` | `VirtualBox` | `Ubuntu` | `Docker`

Запускаю контейнер из образа `nginx`:

```
docker run nginx
```

Сервер запускается и в терминале я вижу output только что запущенного сервера.
При этом я уже не могу посмотреть список запущенных контейнеров на docker-хосте, например так:

```
docker ps -a
```

И не могу остановить контейнер. Единственный вариант - закрыть терминал, завершив процесс `nginx`.

Вопросы:

1. Нормальное ли это поведение docker или я что-то не так делаю?
2. Возможно что бы иметь доступ к терминалу docker-хоста нужно запускать
   контейнер в фоновом режиме (с ключом `-d`)?
3. Можно ли как-то попасть в терминал docker-хоста в моей ситуации?

Comment: Запускайте контейнер в фоновом режиме, а подключайтесь к нему `docker exec -it <имя контейнера> bash или sh` имя контейнера отображается `docker ps`

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -d nginx
docker exec -it <имя контейнера> bash # для запуска команд в контейнере
```